# Flex container with table inside

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, css-grid

I have a container grid with 3 div flex subelements. The first in the header (fixed), the second is the body and the third is the footer (fixed). In the body i have a table. I wish that when I resize the window the table inside the "body" section would remain inside the section by applying overflow-y of the tbody so that the table never "stretches" the section in which it is contended. Some ideas?

In the first image I have the table inside the yellow body with tbody.height=600px. The yellow body is 660px. If i resize the window the situation is as second image. The scollbar appear in the window because the height of the table exceed the yellow height. In this condition the footer (orange) disappear. When I resize the window I would like the window scrollbar to not appear but instead the height of the table is reduced so that only the table scrollbar appears as in the third image.
[image: first image]
[image: second image]
[image: third image]

Comment: Please post the code you've tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Better to see an example.

But for now i can suggest this:

1. Header element has `positon: fixed` and `top: 0`, like you said.
2. Middle element has `padding-top: 100px` (the same as height of Header) and `padding-bottom: 100px` (the same as height of Footer).
3. Footer element has `positon: fixed` and `bottom: 0`, like you said.

And you will use `body` standard scrolling in this case.

Please, add some live example, so I could answer more accurate. You can use https://jsfiddle.net/

**UPDATED**

As I suggested - here is an example with only `body` scrolling

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #1c679a;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #1c9a25;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 50px; /* same as .header height */
  padding-bottom: 50px; /* same as .footer height */
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.table thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px; /* same as .header height */
  background: #ccc;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>last</td>
        <td>last</td>
        <td>last</td>
        <td>last</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for attention. I've updated the question with images.

Comment: Oh. And a HTML and CSS please

Comment: Updated an answer. Using only body scrolling. Look please